# Trimming a string of Int

Tags: c, string, integer

In my program i want to input a string of integer e.g 2107900000. I want to get its length and then want to remove all the 0's and 1's.

Comment: "remove all 0's and 1's". So if your int is 2107900000 you want to get 279?

Comment: Yes. Actually, first i want to remove all 0's and 1's and then iterate through the remaining digits. something like mobile pad program.

Comment: C or C++? Do you want cstring?

Comment: preferably C. Yes Thanks

Comment: If the string with '0's and '1's is not used for anything else, you might get rid of the '0's and '1's at the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not optimal, but you could copy it into another buffer conditionally:

```
 char buffer[20];
 char num[] = "2107900000";
 int j = 0;
 for (int i = 0; num[i]; i++)
 {
   if (num[i] != '0' && num[i] != '1')
   {
     buffer[j] = num[i];
     j++;
   }
 }
 buffer[j] = 0 //null terminator
```

Or you could do it in a single buffer:

```
 char num[] = "2107900000";
 int j = 0;
 for (int i = 0; num[i]; i++)
 {
   if (num[i] != '0' && num[i] != '1')
   {
     num[j] = num[i];
     j++;
   }
 }
 num[j] = 0 //null terminator
```

Comment: By the time you use j, isn't it out of scope?

Comment: @Nyan: you're quite right. (Actually, some compilers allow it, but it isn't standard.) I've adjusted for completeness.

Comment: You're modifying a string literal here (which is undefined behaviour). You should use the declaration `char num[] = "2107900000";` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you want to construct a new string, and I'll assume that you want a function that simply accepts a pointer to such a string: (where it's assumed what's pointed at by `stripped` is at least the same size as what's pointed at by `orig`)

```
void strip_0s_and_1s(char *orig, char *stripped)
{
    // while we haven't seen a null terminator
    while(*orig){
        // if the current character is not a 1 or a 0...
        if(*orig != '0' && *orig != '1'){
           // copy the character
           *stripped= *orig;
           stripped++;
        }
        // increment pointer to old string
        orig++;
    }
    // terminate 'stripped' string
    *stripped= '\0';
}
```

I believe calling this with the same pointer for both arguments should do the replacements in-place...

To address your question about finding length of input strings at runtime you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int len; 
    char str[100]; // max string length of 99+1 null terminator
    scanf("%s", str); 
    len = strlen(str);
    printf("%d", len); 
    return 0; 
}
```

(edit: changed to remove use of `new` as a variable name)

(edit: added info about input strings at runtime and finding string length)

Comment: @Nyan: it's C, there's no conflict here

Comment: @Mark using "new" in your C programs would make to not compatible with C++ compilers. Not a good practice.

Comment: @movieyoda: ok. it's just a variable name, but to stop getting dinged on it I've updated.

Comment: @movieyoda: That's not sound advice anyway. There are a number of things in C that you can't use in C++, just because your C program doesn't compile under C++, it doesn't mean that it isn't a good C program. For example, you can't use `restrict`, `complex`, variable length arrays, `__VA_ARGS__`, `__func__` etc. C and C++ are different languages and should be compiled and interpreted differently.

Comment: @Mark: I'd roll back the answer and use `new` again (the first part of your answer still makes reference to `new`).

Comment: @dreamlax, removed other references to `new`. agree that `new` is an appropriate variable name, but it's just a name, and I'm not particularly attached to it, `stripped` works just as well and seems less... controversial.

Answer (score 1):

`for (i=j=0; s[i]=s[j]; i+=((unsigned)s[j++]-'0'>2));`

OK since there's demand for an explanation, the idea is to iterate through the string with 2 indices, a destination (`i`) and source (`j`). At each step, a character is copied from the source index to the destination index, and since the copy is the loop condition, it will terminate if the character copied is the null terminator. At each iteration, the source index gets incremented (`j++`), but the destination index is only incremented if the character copied was not a 0 or a 1 (if it was one of these two characters, it will simply get overwritten on the next iteration). The test `(unsigned)s[j++]-'0'>2` uses modular arithmetic and the property that the digits 0-9 have consecutive values as characters to perform an optimal test as to whether the source character is outside the range `'0'` to `'1'`, and this truth value (which evaluates to 0 or 1 for false or true, respectively) gets used as the amount to increment the destination index by.